# How to Bind IsSelected Trigger of RadioButton to ContentTemplate (That contains RadioButton) IsSelected Trigger in WPF Custom Controls

Tags: wpf, triggers, custom-controls

I'm having a WPF Prism 4 MVVM application. ViewItemControl is used as Navigation Control to change views using Prism Regions and Views.

```
<Style x:Key="ViewItemControlStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ViewItemControl}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="110" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ViewItemControl}">

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Content" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButtonText}" />
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I implemented a ImageButton Custom Control with Normal, Hover and Selected Triggers to change Image Source.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ImageButton}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <Image Name="ButtonImage" 
            Source="{Binding NormalImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
            Height="{Binding ImageSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
            Width="{Binding ImageSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"/>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />

    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding HoverImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding SelectedImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding DisabledImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I want to define a ViewItemControl to be used as Navigation with Image Button Control in it. I want to bind Isselected Trigger of both the controls to achieve both change of Image Source and Change View.  I need some help in overriding this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an MVVM application, this behavior should be done through a binding to your view model, rather than through XAML directly.

For example, in an application I'm working on, I have a View that has to "modes": "Overview" mode and "Details" mode.  My ToggleButton has a binding like:

```
<ToggleButton IsSelected="{Binding Path=DetailsModeSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

When the toggle button is selected, the binding sets the property `DetailsModeSelected` to true, which in my view model changes some other properties, which the view then picks up through `IPropertyChangeNotification`.

Let your ViewModel do this work, and the particular control (or the view) is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, I have a different scenario I have multiple modules with a separate View and View Module for each Module. In MainWindow I have 2 Prism Regions - MainRegion and NavigationRegion. I have buttons under NavigationRegion. Based on the button Selected, View and ViewModel are activated to display in MainRegion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, but it sounds almost like you need to use Event Aggregation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173(v=PandP.40).aspx), where the view model behind your navigation view (or region) would publish a "Click" event and something would consume those to deicde how to proceed when those buttons are selected or deselected.  I guess I don't have enough background information on your specific situation to be more specific.